# Comparing characters in Python

Tags: python

New to python and working on and on daily studying a word generator. I'm testing restrictions IE set word length, making sure it has at least 1 upper, lowercase and digit in it etc.

```
import random

from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase, ascii_letters, digits

pool = ascii_letters + digits
wordLen=random.randint(7,14)
answer = random.sample(pool, wordLen)

while True:
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in answer):
        answer[random.randrange(len(answer))] = random.choice(ascii_uppercase)
        continue

    if not any(char.islower() for char in answer):
        answer[random.randrange(len(answer))] = random.choice(ascii_lowercase)
        continue

     if not any(char.isdigit() for char in answer):
        answer[random.randrange(len(answer))] = random.choice(digits)
        continue

     break

answer = ''.join(answer)
```

I'd like to add a further restriction -- making sure consecutive chars aren't the same. Now I've studied string manipulation but simply can't find out how I can apply it. Let me show you something I've studied about string comparison

```
if stringx == stringy:
    print 'they are the same'
else
    print 'they are different'
```

I get the actual comparison part but I don't get how I can make the statements run again to generate another character again, disregarding the one it's just made. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: `stringx == stringx` That's always going to be true. You're comparing it to itself.

Comment: Try to give step-by-step instructions for a human, then translate it to Python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @MorganThrapp edited! whoops. meant X and Y.

Answer (score 1):

To continue with your usage of `any()` structure you need to introduce a pairwise iterable like given in the [itertools recipe section](//docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#recipes), and then you could do something like:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

answer = "abcdeffghik"
if any( first_char == second_char for first_char, second_char in pairwise(answer)):
    print "Duplicates exists"
```